# why URLDownloadToFile doesn't work for a text file link?

Tags: c++, winapi, download

In Visual Studio C++ project, I tried to use URLDownloadToFile to download a text file, which locate in a website.
eg.https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt
I can see this file easily from chrome or any browser. so it is a valid link.
while when I tried to use below code to download it. it always prompt an error 0x800c0005(INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND)
But if I change the link to a normal website, eg. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), then it works well.
My Opertion System is WinXP, and IDE is VS2017.
Question:

1. why does it happen? what did I do wrong?
2. how to fix it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <Urlmon.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
    
    int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        printf("URLDownloadToFile test function.\n");
    
        LPCWSTR url = L"https://www.google.com"; // here works well
        
        //BUT change to txt link below will get 800c0005(INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND) error
        //LPCWSTR url = L"https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"; 
    
    
        printf("Url: %S\n", url);
    
        TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    
        GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
        
        wsprintf(path, L"%s\\test.txt", path);
    
        printf("Path: %S\n", path);
    
        HRESULT res = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, url, path, 0, NULL);
    
        if (res == S_OK) {
            printf("Ok\n");
        }
        else if (res == E_OUTOFMEMORY) {
            printf("Buffer length invalid, or insufficient memory\n");
        }
        else if (res == INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE) {
            printf("URL is invalid\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Other error: %d\n", res);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you try with other URLs? DId you try on other computers?

Comment: @Jabberwocky please comment LPCWSTR url = L"https://www.google.com" and uncomment LPCWSTR url = L"https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt". then it should get the error, thanks

Comment: I did exactly that and it works on my computer.

Comment: Same for me. Works fine (Windows 10, x64, x86)

Comment: my pc is winXP x64. and it failed. I tried different website with txt file. always failed

Comment: @Penny do you have an antivirus on your computer? Try to disable/uninstall it. Try to run your code on another computer.

Comment: I disabled my antivirus. still doesn't work. BTW, VS2017 I am using

Comment: Does it only fail with .txt files? Did you try .png or other image files?

Comment: it only failed for txt file. jpg file link works well

Comment: It's probably because XP is tool old, it's possible there are required low level components (security, https, TLS) that are not supported any more by some web servers. Or you need to patch the OS, for example:  https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/262854-enable-tls-12-on-windows-xp/

Comment: @SimonMourier True. I just test win10, VS2017 and VS2019. both work. so it should be winXP issue. thanks

Comment: PS: Visual Studio version has nothing to do in the picture this is a Windows API, you could compile with any C compiler, it wouldn't change anything

Comment: I noticed in my working PC, the urlmon.h using the version in forder C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um. so I copied this urlmon.h and urlmon.lib to my winXP related folders(D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um etc). but still NOT work. So now I don't know how to fix this issue, if I have to use winXP.

Comment: As I said, this has nothing to do with compiler or SDK version. A quote from our sponsor :-) *After 12 years, support for Windows XP ended April 8, 2014. Microsoft will no longer provide security updates or technical support for the Windows XP operating system. It is critical to migrate now to a modern operating system. The best way to migrate from Windows XP to Windows 10 is to buy a new device.* https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-xp-support

Answer (score 0):

After further testing and refer to other person's testing result. I found this issue is from WinXP operation system.
If I run the same code in win10 OS, then it works.
Also even though I copied the working version of urlmon.h and urlmon.lib to winXP's related folder, still it will NOT work.
So I think the only way to fix this issue is to upgrade OS to win10 or higher.